# Any idea about the reason may caused some android phone freezing

Tags: android, performance

I release a new version of my app , already tested by some htc phones.

but recent days, users report that in some moto phone (espically moto defy) ,**don't like normal app freeze which system will show alert dialog**,my app cause phone freeze(the system is not reponsing,people have to plug out the battery then restart). but most of users I asked told the new version is quick smooth~~ bad performance could make system freezing?

Do you know any possible reason may cause my problem? 
or any related system log I can checked?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using threads? If not, then you are blocking the UI thread. You can use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to find performance problems.

Comment: I'm using a lot asynctask.
 not just blocking UI thread ,the system too.

Comment: You have to make a break between few async tasks.